# Underscore - get property from each item, group by and discard rest

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have a collection of objects and I am trying to get all property values called 'impact' from the top level, discard all other properties and child collections, group by the 'impact' and then ideally label the values with the word impact

```
var topics = [{
  var1 : "hi", var2 : "yo", children : [], impact : "high"
}, {
  var1 : "hi", var2 : "yo", children : [], impact : "med"
}, {
  var1 : "hi", var2 : "yo", children : [], impact : "low"
   {
  var1 : "hi", var2 : "yo", children : [], impact : "med"
},
}]
```

And I want `[{impact: "High"}, {impact: "Low"}, {impact: "Med"}]`

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
var impacts = _.chain(topics).pluck("impact").groupBy("impact").value();
```

Comment: Can you describe how it doesn't work? Any error messages? Also, most important, how does `topics` look?

Comment: pluck will return an array of strings. Sounds like you need uniq instead of groupBy

Comment: Hey, I took the liberty to format the code a bit for readability. Just to make it clear: do you need some kind of sorting? Do you want `High` or `high`? The impact values are all the same (`high`), is that intended?

Comment: No problem thanks, it was just sample data. In reality there will be numerous repeats but the values "high", "med" and "low" will all appea. Accepted answer is just what I need.r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with [`sortedUniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedUniqBy) and [`pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) and [`map()`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) within `Lodash`.

```
var o = _.sortedUniqBy(product, function(e) {return e.impact;})
_.map(o, function(e) {return _.pick(e, 'impact')})
```